# Using CSSLint in Node cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, csslint

I am writing Node cli application which will run locally installed CSSLint module by passing parameters. The CSSLint application is started from function cli which is in cli.js file (https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/blob/master/dist/cli.js). How can I include this file and call cli function?

What I have tried.

1. I have tried adding statement var csslint =  require('csslint/dist/cli.js') but this just executes the CSSLint and I am able to pass parameters

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Using-in-a-Node.js-Application), if you y need to call `CSSLint` from your node application/script, you have to do the following:

```
var CSSLint = require('csslint').CSSLint;
var result = CSSLint.verify("h1 { color: red; }");
result.messages.forEach(function (message) {
    console.log("%s (line %d, col %d): %s", message.type, message.line, message.col, message.message);
});
```